# Is $\cosh(t^2)$ of exponential order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Is 
$\cosh(t^2)$
of exponential order?

I know that it isn't, but I am unsure as to why.
Also why is $\cosh(t) $ of exponential order?

Comment: It is because $\cosh(x)=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$

Comment: By not of exponential order do you mean "bigger than exponential order?"

Answer (score 0):

For $\cosh(t^2) $ which is just $\ {e^{t^2} + e^{-t^2} \over 2}$ you only need to show that $\ lim_{t \to \infty} {{e^{t^2} + e^{-t^2} \over 2} \over e^{at}} = \infty  $ for all `a`

$\ lim_{t \to \infty} {{e^{t^2} + e^{-t^2} \over 2} \over e^{at}} =  {{1\over 2}lim_{ t \to \infty} {{e^{t(t-a)}}} + {1\over 2}lim_{t \to \infty}{e^{-t(t+a)} }} = {{1\over 2}lim_{ t \to \infty} {{e^{t(t-a)}}}} + 0 = \infty  $

For $\cosh(t)$ can show that $\ cosh(t) < Me^{\alpha t} $ for (t>T):

$\ cosh(x) = {e^{t} + e^{-t} \over 2} < e^t  \implies {e^{t} + e^{-t}} < 2e^t \implies {e^{-t}} < e^t $

which is true for $\ t>0 $ $\ ( M = 1, \alpha =1, T = 0 ) $